# SVN externals appear as unversioned

Tags: macos, svn, svn-externals

In my SVN repo I have the following structure:

```
<myRepo>/shared
<myRepo>/project
```

And I want to include the `shared` folder as an external within the `project` folder so I have:

```
<myRepo>/project/shared
```

So I defined an external property on the `project` folder like this:

```
https://myServer.com/<myRepo>/shared "shared"
```

I commit the change and update the `project` working copy and the code is checked out including the shared folder. **However my SVN client (Versions for Mac) marks the folder `<myRepo>/project/shared` as "Unversioned" not as an external.** Yet the externals property seems to be set correctly when I do `$svn propget svn:externals project`

What am I doing wrong?